# Python manage.py command showing ImportError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-manage.py, makemigrations

When hit the command `python manage.py makemigrations`,
I am getting the import error.
The error is like this

`**ImportError : Module 'Backend.apps'does not contain a 'BackendConfigrest_framework'class. Choices are : 'BackendConfig'**`

Comment: Post your settings.py's INSTALLED_APPS variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings.py, change line where your "Backend" application is under the INSTALLED_APP variable from:

```
'Backend.apps.BackendConfigrest_framework'
```

to:

```
'Backend.apps.BackendConfig',
'rest_framework',
```

Comment: If this solved your problem then make sure to select this as the answer. :)

Comment: Thank-you Naeem Khan for solving my doubt. Actually this error showed up because i missed a comma after 'Bacend.apps.BackendConfig'